# How to convert a C string to a D string?

Tags: string, casting, d, c-strings

If I have a C string, which is a pointer to a null terminated character array, how do I convert it to a regular D string?

The reason I'd like to know this is because I'm currently using an external C library which on error returns C strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert a c string to a d string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508144/how-to-convert-a-c-string-to-a-d-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `std.conv.to` function:

```
char* c_str = c_function();
string s = to!string(c_str);
```

You can also slice and/or duplicate the c string:

```
char[] arr = c_str[0 .. strlen(c_str)];
string s = arr.idup;
```

and so on.